# Check my proof of $X,Y$ independent $\implies$ $X$ and $\mathbb1_{Y \le a}$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ are independent

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a measurable space and $X$ and $Y$ two independent integrable random variables.
>   Are $X$ and $\tilde{Y} := \mathbb{1}_{Y \le a}$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ independent?

**My proof:**
We need to show that
$$
\mathbb{P}(X \in B_1, \tilde{Y} \in B_2)
= \mathbb{P}(X \in B_1) \mathbb{P}(\tilde{Y} \in B_2)
$$
holds for all Borel sets $B_1, B_2$.

I will make a case distinction for $B_2$.
Since it is Borel, we can write it as $B_2 = (- \infty, z]$ for some $z \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Case 1: $z < 0$.**
Then $\{ \tilde{Y} \in B_2)\} = \{ \omega \in \Omega: \tilde{Y}(\omega) \in (- \infty, z]\} = \emptyset$.
Therefore we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X \in B_1, \tilde{Y} \in B_2)
& = \mathbb{P}(X \in B_1, \emptyset)
= 0
=  \mathbb{P}(X \in B_1) \cdot 0 
= \mathbb{P}(X \in B_1) \mathbb{P}(\emptyset).
\end{align}

**Case 2: $z \in (0,1)$.**
Then $\{ \tilde{Y} \in B_2)\} = \{ \omega \in \Omega: \tilde{Y}(\omega) \in (- \infty, z]\} = \{ Y > a\}$.
By independence of $X$ and $Y$ we see that the equality is fullfilled.

**Case 3: $z \ge 1$.**
$\{ \tilde{Y} \in B_2)\} = \{ Y \le a\}$. This then works similarly to case 2.

**Is this correct and / or is there an easier way to see this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X,Y $ be independent random variables and let $f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R $ be Borel-measurable functions.

Then for Borel-measurable sets $A,B $:$$P(f(X)\in A, g(Y)\in B)=P(X\in f^{-1}(A),Y\in g^{-1}(B))=P(X\in f^{-1}(A))P (Y\in g^{-1}(B))=P(f(X)\in A)P (g(Y)\in B)$$proving that $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent.

In your case you can take the identity for $f $ and $1_{(-\infty,a]}$ for $g$.

Also observe that being integrable is not demanded.

Comment: Is my approach correct, though?

Comment: $\tilde Y=1_{(-\infty, a]}(Y) $

Comment: Maybe. I must admit haven't checked because I feel so much reluctance against that. This because it can be done so much easyer. This time I choose for "or" and not for "and".